# How to fix "android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing is experimental and unsupported" which is logged as a warning?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I added a new option in my **gradle.properties** file:

`android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true`

But I got the following warning from the compiler/builder:

> WARNING: The option setting
>   `android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true` is experimental and
>   unsupported.

Also I tried to make it `false`, but I got the following message:

> Gradle may disable incremental compilation as the following annotation
>   processors are not incremental: compiler-1.1.1.jar
>   (android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1), compiler-4.8.0.jar
>   (com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0),
>   butterknife-compiler-8.6.0.jar
>   (com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0). Consider setting the
>   experimental feature flag
>   android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in the
>   gradle.properties file to run annotation processing in a separate task
>   and make compilation incremental.

**Environment:**

JRE 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Android Studio 3.2.1 Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
Gradle 4.10.3
Android Gradle plugin: 3.3.1

**Android doc:**

> When you include this flag, the Android Gradle plugin
>   executes the annotation processors in a separate task and allows the
>   Java compilation task to run incrementally.
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what is it you're asking?

Comment: @AivarasPrudnikovas I'm talking about those warnings... how to fix them? `WARNING: The option setting android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true is experimental and unsupported.`

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this problem? I am having this problem after I updated to 3.3.1.

Comment: @TaehyunPark , Not yet... had to rollback to Gradle plugin 3.2.1

Answer (score 4):

Just remove android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true from your gradle.properties file and run your project.

Answer (score 3):

This is a new feature. The warning is just that. It already works.

The warning will disappear in a future version of Android Studio.

Answer (score -3):

You need to add `kapt` dependencies for compiler dependency in your app gradle file.

For example: You should add below line in your app gradle file for android lifecycle dependency.

```
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycleVersion"
```

Also add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in your app gradle top level to make it enable.

If you are using dagger you should also add kapt dependency for compiler like shown above.